# Why I can't vote for myself in Regiment Election?

Tags: erepublik

Today is 15th, when we cast our votes to `Party President` and `Regiment Captain` of `Military Unit`. I've Participated as a candidate for my MU (`Marcos, 7th Regiment`). I know that I can vote for myself in all other elections, but I can't see vote button there in regiment election screen with my name. There're no other candidates, so can't see vote button for anyone.
So is it due to no other candidates available or due to the fact that I can't vote for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it, there're only one vote available to you as a Voter on 15th of every month. You can either  vote for a Party President or you can vote for your regiment captain.